# How to access a specific piece of info from .json in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am a new programmer in Javascript/JSON so sorry if this is an easy question but here goes: I am trying to use Reddits json url and was told this was the easiest way to do it (I imported jquery):

```
$(function () {
$.getJSON(
    "https://www.reddit.com/r/all/new/.json",
    function (data) {
        $("#POST").html(JSON.stringify(data));

    });
});
```

I am wondering how i would go about getting a specific thing from the json for example just the title of the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once your JSON document is loaded into a variable (we say a dictionary), it can be accessed by indexes (brackets notation, `[]`) or properties (dotted notation).

Usually if the keys or the dictionary do not contain spaces, then you can access them by dotting them. Examples under NodeJS:

```
# JSON document
> j = {
  'a test' : 3,
  b : "test",
  c : {
    "nested" : true
  },
  d : [1,2,3]
}

> j['a test']
3

> j.c.nested
true

> j.d[1]
2
```

Comment: could you show me how to do this with the specific json im using (reddits) because its a lot longer then that (and frankly more intimidating)

Comment: You did not post the JSON but I am glad I helped, do not hesitate to mark the question as answered ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the structure of JSON response, you just need to iterate through the "children" array, and print out the "title" within it.

Assuming you have the response JSON in responseData variable, below code would print the Titles from all the posts

```
responseData.children.forEach(PrintTitle);

function PrintTitle(post) {
  alert("The title of this post is: " + post.title);
}
```